# How to modify category tree in Magento admin?

Tags: magento-1.9, category-tree, edit

I want to add custom icon/text in category at selected place in screenshot. I don't know which file I need to edit to modify the category tree. Can anyone help me in getting out of this?

[image]

Comment: You can start from here magentoroot/js/extjs/ext-tree.js

Comment: @EmiproTechnologiesPvt.Ltd. I am unable to understand where i need to change in this file. Please suggest.

Comment: In this file there is html code for add folder icon and after that there code of display category name , after that you can add your html code for display icon, search in file "x-tree-node-icon" that code is for display folder icon so you can start from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to add a text with the category name you can just over ride the class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Category_Tree.

In that class you can find a function like

```
public function buildNodeName($node)
{
    $result = $this->escapeHtml($node->getName());
    if ($this->_withProductCount) {
         $result .= ' (' . $node->getProductCount() . ')';
    }
    return $result;
}
```

You can just add your text like.

```
$result.='Your Text';
```